# Why is my POST not working after getting values

Tags: python, jquery, bottle

So I am getting user input from a template that uses css and jQuery, then I'm posting that data back supposedly on click. However, I am not able to access the data as I believe it is not being posted back.

I believe my ajax code is not recognizing the click, can someone please help me out. I spent the whole day trying to figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
#This is main code
from bottle import run, route, request, template, static_file, post

def main():

    #This is main code
    @route('/assets/<filepath:path>')
    def server_static(filepath):
        return static_file(filepath, root='./Gui/assets')

    @route('/')
    def home():
        return template('indexTest')

    @post('/home')
    def home():
        radius=request.forms['radius']
        noTr=request.forms['noOdTurbines']
        result=radius+noTr
        return ({'result': result})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

this is jQuery code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Example</title>

<script  type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('form').on('submit',(function(event){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home"
                data: {
                    radius: $('#radius').val(),
                    noOfTurbines: $('#noOfTurbines').val()
             },
             error:function(){
             alert('Error: something is wrong with values!!')
             }


            })

        event.preventDefault();


       });
     }));

 </script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/home">
<div id="exampleAccount" role="tabpanel">
    <div id="exampleAccountForm">
        </div>
  <div>
      <label for="radius">Radius of Swept-Area of Wind turbine: 
 </label>
            <input type="text"  id="radius" required>
        </div>
         <div >
            <label for="noOfTurbines">Number of Wind turbines: </label>
            <input type="text"  id="noOfTurbines" required>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div >
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
                          id="submit">Finish</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that bottle does not support this?

Comment: put an alert in your ajax code to see if its being hit

Comment: I don't see a `<form>` element in the template.

Comment: @JohnGordon the code is really big, I just included the relevant part. You're right though I should have included it. I think my issue is with bottle requests.forms. I usually use request.forms.get() but this time I'm dealing with a dictionary. So I used request.forms['first'] but it didn't work. I am getting "return self.dict[key][-1]" this error now.

Comment: @Programnik I did, but I think the issue is not posting. I am struggling to retrieve the data after it has been posted using request.forms

Comment: is there a way to read dictionaries like the ones provided by the jQuery code above in bottle, I was checking the documentation but I didn't see any.

Comment: Please check the edit in the above code, this should be reproducible.@PaulRooney

Comment: Best I can see there is an issue on this line `radius=request.forms['radius']`. I'm sorry I don't know much about bottle, so I can't offer a solution. It is getting submitted though. Probably the best thing is to read the bottle docs and tutorials and see if you can see what is wrong in your code.

Comment: You have use `name` not `id`.  You have no names in your form, so bottle doesn't build the request.

Answer (score 1):

I have problems with the request.forms type of multidict, so I convert to dict and this solves all my problems.  I usually merge the post and string URL objects into one just to make it more flexible.

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
```

Just remember, that bottle uses the `name` not the `id` of the form element in a post.  So make sure all inputs have a `name`.

(Which I do not see in your example)